# cURL and timeouts

Tags: curl, cross-domain

Is there a way to check to make sure a server exists, before attempting to connect via cURL?

Trying to find a good handler to prevent my server form attempting a cURL connection to a server that has been taken offline?  Best I've found\thought of is attempting to ping it beforehand, but this method still requires me to wait for the ping timeout, which can also create a whole group of other issues.

Comment: you can set your own timeout for curl:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout/94612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` - if you really want to determine if the server responds before, though, i guess you can use socket_create / socket_setopt & SO_RCVTIMEO / socket_connect , to see if it answers within the specified time before calling curl. but why would you want to do that if you can just handle a CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMOUT error instead?

Comment: For some reason it wasn't clicking that anything I use to test a timeout is just as slow as waiting for the cURL itself to time out.  Thank you, for the response cleared the stupid out of my head and I've now fixed it.